# How do I add type definitions for React's useContext?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
interface AppState {
 jwt: string | null,
 isSignedIn: boolean
 isLoading : boolean;
 newUser : boolean;
 avatar : Avatar | null;
 alerts : SnackBarAlert[];
}
const initialState : AppState = { isLoading : true, isSignedIn : false, newUser : false, hero : null, alerts : [], jwt : null };

const store = createContext(initialState);
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(store);
```

When I hover over state or dispatch, I get "Property 'state' does not exist on type 'AppState'." and "Property 'dispatch' does not exist on type 'AppState'."

I think to myself 'Oh, I need to tell useContext what type the store is. But when I try to describe the store....

```
interface Store {
  state: AppState
  dispatch: <Payload = {}>(action: Action<Payload>) => void
} 
const { state, dispatch } = useContext<Store>(store);
```

'store' becomes highlighted telling me:
"Argument of type 'Context' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context'.
The types of 'Provider.propTypes.value' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'Validator' is not assignable to type 'Validator'.
Type 'AppState' is not assignable to type 'Store'."

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked into the type definitions:

```
/**
 * Accepts a context object (the value returned from `React.createContext`) and returns the current
 * context value, as given by the nearest context provider for the given context.
 *
 * @version 16.8.0
 * @see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext
 */
function useContext<T>(context: Context<T>/*, (not public API) observedBits?: number|boolean */): T;
```

This means your state is represented by `T`. You get `Context<T>` by calling `React.createContext`, which is passed as parameter `context` to the function `useContext`. `useContext` returns the given state `T` itself. In your case the state is given by

```
interface AppState {
  jwt: string | null,
  isSignedIn: boolean
  isLoading : boolean;
  newUser : boolean;
  avatar : Avatar | null;
  alerts : SnackBarAlert[];
}
```

But by using the destructuring assignment `const { state, dispatch } = useContext<Store>(store);` you assume `state` and `dispatch` is part of your state, which is not true as per definition above.

**So you don't have to add type definitions for `useContext`. It is inferred automatically. You only have to respect, what it infers.**

**This also means that you have to define and provide a `dispatch` function by yourself, if you want to provide a means to change the values in your state.**